# Why is \x00 not converted to \0 by repr

Tags: python, repr

Here is an interesting oddity about Python's repr:

The tab character `\x09` is represented as `\t`. However this convention does not apply for the null terminator.

**Why is `\x00` represented as `\x00`, rather than `\0`?**

Sample code:

```
# Some facts to make sure we are on the same page
>>> '\x31' == '1'
True
>>> '\x09' == '\t'
True
>>> '\x00' == '\0'
True

>>> x = '\x31'
>>> y = '\x09'
>>> z = '\x00'
>>> x
'1' # As Expected
>>> y
'\t' # Okay
>>> z
'\x00' # Inconsistent - why is this not \0
```

Comment: Because it's just not commonplace enough. `\0` is not the only such escape that's not used in `repr()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think the question might still be rephrased as "Where in the Python library is '\x09' translated to '\t'?"... because then you could check what is and isn't converted.

Comment: See [Is asking "why" questions on language specifications still considered primarily opinion-based?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio) on [meta]. Granted, this is an implementation decision, but the same considerations apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer: because that's not a specific escape that *is* used. String representations only use the single-character escapes `\\`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, (plus `\'` when both `"` and `'` characters are present) because there are explicit tests for those.

The rest is either considered printable and included as-is, or included using a longer escape sequence (depending on the Python version and string type, `\xhh`, `\uhhhh` and `\Uhhhhhhhh`, always using the shortest of the 3 options that'll fit the value).

Moreover, when generating the `repr()` output, for a string consisting of a null byte followed by a *digit* from `'1'` through to `'7'` (so `bytes([0x00, 0x49])`, or `bytes([0x00, 0x4A])`, etc), you can't just use `\0` in the output without then also having to escape the following digit. `'\01'` is a single octal escape sequence, and not the same value as `'\x001'`, which is two bytes. While forcing the output to always use three octal digits (e.g. `'\0001'`) could be a work-around, it is just simpler to stick to a standardised, simpler escape sequence format. Scanning ahead to see if the next character is an octal digit and switching output styles would just produce confusing output (imagine the question on SO: *What is the difference between `'\x001'` and `'\0Ol'`?*)

The output *is* always consistent. Apart from the single quote (which can appear either with `'` or `\'`, depending on the presence of `"` characters), Python will always use *same escape sequence style* for a given codepoint.

If you want to study the code that produces the output, you can find the Python 3 `str.__repr__` implementation in the [`Objects/unicodeobject.c` `unicode_repr()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd9c2ce7acaef45f23c2659b854fc9925096d040/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12537-L12699), which uses

```c
/* Escape quotes and backslashes */
if ((ch == quote) || (ch == '\\')) {
    PyUnicode_WRITE(okind, odata, o++, '\\');
    PyUnicode_WRITE(okind, odata, o++, ch);
    continue;
}


/* Map special whitespace to '\t', \n', '\r' */
if (ch == '\t') {
    PyUnicode_WRITE(okind, odata, o++, '\\');
    PyUnicode_WRITE(okind, odata, o++, 't');
}
else if (ch == '\n') {
    PyUnicode_WRITE(okind, odata, o++, '\\');
    PyUnicode_WRITE(okind, odata, o++, 'n');
}
else if (ch == '\r') {
    PyUnicode_WRITE(okind, odata, o++, '\\');
    PyUnicode_WRITE(okind, odata, o++, 'r');
}
```

for single-character escapes, followed by additional checks longer escapes below. For Python 2, a [similar but shorter `PyString_Repr()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5744a3362945e0d9cd7bb24ed5ebcedba8822d4c/Objects/stringobject.c#L931-L992) does much the same thing.

Comment: This is brilliant and really insightful. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If it tried to use `\0`, then it would have to special-case when numbers immediately followed it, to prevent them from being interpreted as an octal literal. Always using `\x00` is simpler and always correct.